# Should a SQL Server tempDB partition be shared by the cluster?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cluster, failovercluster, diskmanagement

We have a 2-node SQL Server 2008 RS cluster. The data and log partitions are shared among the cluster nodes. Does the tempDB partition need to be shared as well, or will local server node storage suffice?

Comment: I think this question might have the answer I was looking for: http://serverfault.com/a/240474/563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data & log files should be place on shared storage for a failover cluster.  SQL Server 2012 will support tempdb on local storage, but not SQL Server 2008.

[Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2012, see the section: Storage Types for Data Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx)